# SQL Server : how can I MERGE with a dynamic column?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, I have a merge statement that looks like this:

```
MERGE dbo.MyTable AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM dbo.StageTable)

WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN 
      UPDATE SET target.[StartTime] = source.[UnknownColumn]
```

My `source` table contains columns in randomly generated order. In other words, the "StartTime" column in the `target` table could be equal to Column1 or Column2 or Column3 etc., but it will always contain the words "StartTime" somewhere in the column.

How can I set the target column equal to the correct column, when I don't know the correct column's position in the source table? The only thing I know about the correct column is that is that it contains a specific string...

Comment: My research indicates that CONTAINS may be useful here, but I'm not sure how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic T-SQL statement. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@ColumnName SYSNAME;

SELECT @ColumnName = [name]
FROM [sys].[columns]
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[StackOverflow]')
    AND [name] LIKE '%StartTime%';


SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = N'MERGE dbo.MyTable AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM dbo.StageTable)

WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN 
      UPDATE SET target.[StartTime] = source.[' + @ColumnName + '];';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```